# Load DataGridViewImageRow Async

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, datagridview

So I'm loading a set of 100+ rows for a `DataGridView` that has an `DataGridViewImageColumn` inside it.

Currently, my code is waiting for `req.GetImageFromURL(t)` to download the image before each row can be added to the DataGridView as this is taking a long time per row The DataGridView is unresponsive until all images have been downloaded, and all the images added

Is there any way to get the `DataGridView` to present all the other information in the view and then present the images once they have been downloaded. perhaps using an Async method?

How I'm currently creating the rows for the `DataGridView`

```
   foreach (var mast in x)
   {
       var t = req.GetUrl(mast.Id);
       mastGrid.Rows.Add(req.GetImageFromURL(t), a, b, c, d);
   }
```

My GetImageFromUrl Method:

```
    public Image GetImageFromURL(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();
        return Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
```

Comment: For the user that flaged as "unclear what you're asking" it's very clear what the OP is asking`, He's wanting the grid to load as fast as possible while not awaiting image download.

Comment: if you check this https://pastebin.com/BtVRgRA1 this will do what you need but I don't recommend it you will be loading every image into memory if they are large images you use all available memory, i would recommend you look up VirtualMode on DataGridView https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624(v=vs.110).aspx and download your images to a cache directory and if downloaded use that one if not download them then use it using a similar method to the pastebin.